# Profiting on selling physical stocks?

Tags: stocks, profitability

My dad gave me a share of Disney a few years back. The price of a Disney share has barely changed since then, but I'm wondering if I can sell the physical share for more than on an exchange.

For example, the physical share is worth more because it is tangible. The very reason hardcover books sell for more than ebooks is because they are tangible, physical objects.

I can probably buy physical Disney shares through direct-options for under $130.00 per share.

Is it a profitable thing to buy these and try to re-sell them for more outside of digital exchanges?

Here's an example:

50 shares @ $125 = $6,250.

Sell 50 shares for @ $135 = $6,750.

Profit = $500 and no brokerage fees through exchanges/etc.

Answer (score 3):

> I can probably buy physical Disney shares through direct-options for under $130.00 per share.

[Disney and quite a few other companies](http://www.usatoday.com/story/money/business/2013/10/09/disney-stock-certificates-head-to-never-never-land/2956765/) have stopped physical shares certificates. These are expensive to print / maintain and result in fraud, cost on change in ownership.

However the older share certificates are still valid. These could be collectibles. Note they are going way higher than actual price, plus these certificates would have specific names written on them. Hence someone who buys these when turned in to Disney for name change, will get an electronic shares.

So there could be tons of paper shares from Disney, that may keep changing hands ... it depends how much demand there is for such collectibles.

However it is to be noted that in the Disney's company records the share is held by "xyz" and they are the ones who would get dividends, any splits, bonus if any declared in future.